# Duplicate form submission in Wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

In Spring I usually did a redirect-after-submit to prevent the user of submitting a form multiple times by pressing F5. Does wicket handle this out of the box or do I also need to take this into account when developing my form pages?

I don't have a problem with this yet but I would like to know in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Wicket handles this automatically because of its stateful nature and page versioning.
See also this answer of your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8082042/532331

Comment: Tx, also learned from other sources that Wicket by default does a redirect so no issues here.